# React Js map function gives an "not a function" error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, map-function

I'm trying to map through objects to display their values in my React JS project. It looks like I can't access values of the objects within objects using the map function, values simply are not displayed, or if I try to use (.split("/p")) it gives me an error saying "split is not a function".

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-js-map-puv0q?file=/src/studies.js:0-1232)

this is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { studies } from "./studies";

import "./styles.css";

const Data = ({ title, text, number, numberdesc }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ margin: "1rem" }}>{title}</div>
      <div style={{ margin: "1rem" }}>{text}</div>
      <div>{number}</div>
      <div>{numberdesc}</div>
    </>
  );
};

function App() {
  const appComponent = studies.map((post, i) => {
    console.log(studies);
    return (
      <Data
        key={i}
        number={studies[i].post.number}
        title={studies[i].post.title}
        text={studies[i].post.text
          .split("/p")
          .reduce((total, line) => [total, <br />, <br />, line])}
      />
    );
  });
  return <>{appComponent}</>;
}

export default App;
```

and **{studies}** file:

```
export const studies = [
  {
    id: "first",
    text: "1st Post",
    post: {
      data: [
        { number: "100", numberdesc: "description1" },
        { number: "200", numberdesc: "description2" },
        { number: "300", numberdesc: "description3" }
      ],

      text: [
        {
          title: "Title1 from the 1st post",
          text: "Text1 from the 1st post."
        },
        {
          title: "Title2 from the 1st post",
          text: "Text2 from the 1st post."
        },
        {
          title: "Title3 from the 1st post",
          text: "Text3 from the 1st post"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: "second",
    text: "2nd Post",
    post: {
      data: [
        { number: "100", numberdesc: "description1" },
        { number: "200", numberdesc: "description2" },
        { number: "300", numberdesc: "description3" }
      ],

      text: [
        {
          title: "Title1 from the 2nd post",
          text: "Text1 from the 2nd post "
        },
        {
          title: "Title2 from the 2nd post",
          text: "Text2 /p from the 2nd post"
        },
        {
          title: "Title3 from the 2nd post",
          text: "Text3 from the 2nd post"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

What I want to do is to access **data and text** values for each post, and display them in my Project. Any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: do a console.log(studies) and put here the output, and also in which line you written the console.log

Comment: since you are using map over studies I suggest you use `post` instead of `studies[i].post`. `text` property is an array containing both `title` and `text` there not a string.

map is not the only issue you have actually. `post.number` and `post.title` returns undefined, they are actually contained inside `data` and `text` arrays respectively. each post has 3 different `number` and `title` attributes. you may need to do another iteraction if you want each `Data` to have a unique `number` and `title`.

Comment: @buzatto, you mean `post` instead of `studies[i]` (or `post.post` instead of `studies[i].post`), right?

Comment: @tao yeas that's right, It should be `post` to `studies[i]`, not `studies[i].post` like I wrote at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
function App() {
  const appComponent = studies.map(study =>
    study.post.data.map((data, k) => (
      <Data
        key={k}
        number={data.number}
        numberdesc={data.numberdesc}
        title={study.post.text[k].title}
        text={study.post.text[k].text}
      />
    ))
  );
  return <>{appComponent}</>;
}
```

Note I arbitrarily zipped `data[k]`'s `number` and `numberdesc` with `text[k]`'s `title` and `text`, but that might not necessarily be what you intend to display.

The above will likely break in case your `data` and `text` arrays do not have the same length in any given `study`.

See it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-js-map-gl1j6?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, marking as correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be wanting to `.map` your array of content. For example:

```
text={studies[i].post.text.map(t => <p><strong>{t.title}</strong>: {t.text}</p>)}
```

might replace the existing line that is breaking.